# How to bring the footnote back to the footer of the page when using thmtools

Tags: footnotes, thmtools

I use `thmtools` for my theorems. But when I use it, my footnotes done with `\footnote{foo}` don't appear in the footer, they are in the footer of the theorem.

I declare my theorem like this

```
\declaretheorem[shaded={bgcolor=red},sibling=definition]{lemma}
```

This is the way I use them

```
\begin{lemma}
  Lorem ipsum\footnote{bar}.    
\end{lemma}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Try `\begin{lemma}
  Lorem ipsum\footnotemark.    
\end{lemma} \footnotetext{bar}`

Comment: @Jubobs Thank you very much. It works great. Could you please post it as an answer, so that I can accept it. Also thank you for the link to the starter guide, I couldn't find it.

Comment: No problem. I'm pretty sure a similar question to yours has been asked (and answered) on the site already; as a result, your question is likely to be closed as a duplicate and can be left "unanswered".

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't find an exact duplicate ([this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/574874/208544) is close, and feel free to correct me) I'll go ahead and post an answer from jub0b's comment. Use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem{definition}
\declaretheorem[shaded={bgcolor=red},sibling=definition]{lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
Lorem ipsum\footnotemark.
\end{lemma}
\footnotetext{bar}

\end{document}
```