# How to place footnote outside box environment

Tags: footnotes, theorems, boxes, mdframed

My issue is the following:
[image]
The footnote gets placed inside the box. However, I want it to be placed and numbered like a normal footnote. How can that be made possible?

I provided an MWE for my specific design:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Definition}
\newenvironment{ltheorem}
{\begin{mdframed}[topline=false,rightline=false,bottomline=false]
        \hspace*{-\parindent}%
        \rlap{\smash{\colorbox{white}{\strut\hspace{\parindent}}}}%
        \begin{theorem}}
        {\end{theorem}\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{ltheorem}[\textbf{Theorem}]
        \kant[1]\footnote{\kant[2]}
    \end{ltheorem}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314375/why-does-parbox-lose-footnotes?r=SearchResults&s=1|46.5619

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a page-global footnote, you:

1. issue a `\footnotemark` in the place where you want the mark to be, and
2. issue a `\footnotetext{whatever}` at the page level.

Here:

```latex
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{ltheorem}[\textbf{Theorem}]
        \kant[1]\footnotemark
    \end{ltheorem}

    la la la la \footnotetext{\kant[2]}
    
\end{document}
```

If you need more than one footnote, the thing get more complex; you can see for example [How to make multiple \footnotemark and \footnotetext match?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370600/how-to-make-multiple-footnotemark-and-footnotetext-match)